# How to prefill a textbox with a value using ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this as HTML:

```html
<div class="row" ng-app="">
    <form>
         <input type="text" ng-model="link" name="link"
                class="form-control" id="yesklinkshjhs3" 
                value="hello" placeholder='Link for your post.'>
    </form>

    <small><a href='' ng-bind='link' class="thelink"></a></small>
</div>
```

I have created this HTML just to show the problem so there may be some mistakes but the main issue is that the textbox cant is prefilled with any value if I use the `ng-model` there.

If I remove the `ng-model` the value is there. I need the form to be prefilled to facility the editing of a post, how should I do that ??

I have tried removing the `ng-model` it works then but I need the `ng-model` there to show the realtime change in the next box.
I am new to the `angular`.

Here is a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/iamrahulkumar001/wksapfr2/

The textbox does not have any prefilled value ...

Comment: Side note: If you are new to angular, you are following wrong Angular version, you need Angular 2+ as AngularJS userbase base is shrinking and you dont want to learn wrong framework that you are not going to use.

Comment: You can prefill the `link` on your controller, `$scope.link = 'your value'`

Comment: @Rikin oh ok sure, i will take care of that for sure.

Comment: @penleychan how to use that ?? please give me little more details i am really new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things with your JSFiddle that need to be fixed. First, you'll need to use the `ng-app` directive to bootstrap your application. Second, you should be registering `MyCtrl` as a controller. Third, you can set a default value for `inputValue` in your `MyCtrl` controller. Below is a working example demonstrating these three items.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', MyCtrl);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.inputValue = 'sjks';
    $scope.$watch('inputValue', function(thisValue) {
        $scope.inputValueEcho = thisValue;
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <input data-ng-model="inputValue" data-ng-trim="false" value='sjks'/>
    <p>This value: ----<span data-ng-bind="inputValue"></span>----</p>
    <p>This value (echo): ----<span data-ng-bind="inputValueEcho">dddddd</span>----</p>
</div>
```